# terminate called after thrwing an instance of 'NSException'

Tags: iphone, xcode

***plz help me to resolve this
i m a learner***

```
[Session started at 2011-01-10 14:32:07 +0530.]
2011-01-10 14:32:10.595 balls[963:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "ballsViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x025a5b99 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0239a40e objc_exception_throw + 47
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x0255e238 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
 3   CoreFoundation                      0x0255e1aa +[NSException raise:format:] + 58
 4   UIKit                               0x00363a40 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 295
 5   UIKit                               0x00361675 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
 6   UIKit                               0x0036154f -[UIViewController view] + 56
 7   balls                               0x00001fc1 -[ballsAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 74
 8   UIKit                               0x002b7f27 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
 9   UIKit                               0x002ba3b0 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 346
 10  UIKit                               0x002c43ec -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1958
 11  UIKit                               0x002bcb3c -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
 12  UIKit                               0x002c19bf _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7672
 13  GraphicsServices                    0x030f0822 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
 14  CoreFoundation                      0x02586ff4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
 15  CoreFoundation                      0x024e7807 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
 16  CoreFoundation                      0x024e4a93 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
 17  CoreFoundation                      0x024e4350 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
 18  CoreFoundation                      0x024e4271 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
 19  UIKit                               0x002b9c6d -[UIApplication _run] + 625
 20  UIKit                               0x002c5af2 UIApplicationMain + 1160
 21  balls                               0x00001f54 main + 102
 22  balls                               0x00001ee5 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Comment: Post some code first. It looks like you haven't added an outlet for your xib yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to ballsViewController's xib and check whether the View is connected to Files Owner or not.

If not than control click on the View and drag the mouse to the files owner

Comment: Thanks u so much..and sorry for so late reply